# Did not get push notification on my device but its shows on Log

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying push notification using GCM. All code done. It's working but problem is that the notification shows on my Log but not in my device. Please help me how would i get this on my device.

```
- (void) showReceivedMessage:(NSNotification *) notification
{ 
    message = notification.userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"]; 

 [self showAlert:@"Message received" withMessage:message]; 
}
```

Comment: what code u write for show notification ?

Comment: - (void) showReceivedMessage:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    message = notification.userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];
    [self showAlert:@"Message received" withMessage:message];
}

Comment: Did you add  "priority": "high" parameter in your JSON ?

Comment: @SaraMichael i did not get you. where should i add this priority in my code?

Comment: when i run my application on my phone connected with xcode.i get push notification there on my Log .